# How many addresses under each subnet

Tags: ip, tcp

I'm studying IP classes and the topic of subnetting is confusing me.
I'm doing some practice questions and the question I'm stuck on requires me to find number of addresses under each subnet.
What I have so far is, a block 211.17.180.0/24 from which I was able to obtain subnet mask /24 = 255.255.255.0. And that there's 32 subnets. I'm not too sure how to proceed from this point. Normally, I would say there's 254 usable addresses (excluding 211.17.180.0 and 211.17.180.255) but I'm not sure how to deal with 32 subnets.

Ok, I may have figured out how to solve this problem
Since there are 32 subnets, I multiply by 2, getting 64 addresses(multiply because there are 2 unusable address per every subnet)
Then, 256-64=192/32=6, so, there are 6 addresses per every subnet in this block.
I'm not sure if this is the right way to solve this problem, some confirmation would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the problem mentions that there are 32 subnets inside the /24 block.

Your answer is correct, here's an alternative way to think about it if you think this is confusing:

If there are 32 subnets, it means you'll need 5 bits to encode subnet identification (211.17.180.0/29 through 211.17.180.31/29), which leaves you with 3 usable bits for the host IP on each subnet; since 2 addresses are unusable on each subnet, we get at most 2^3-2 = 6 usable addresses per subnet.